# Why does interface in typescript behaves like model?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my html code

```
<form #incomesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveMonthlyIncome(incomesForm.value)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="6">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Monthly Income</ion-label>
            <ion-input ngModel name="amount"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6">
          <ion-button type="submit" color="dark">Save</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
```

Then in my ts file,

```
saveMonthlyIncome(income: Income){
    alert(income.amount);
  }
```

Income is an interface which as far as I understand, it is just a contract and cannot hold values.
Why is it that the amount was saved in the income variable?

Comment: `income` is some object that fulfills the `Income` contract. Therefore, it has an `amount`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces

Comment: you are passing the entire form in the ngSubmit, not just the income

Answer (score 1):

The value itself is not stored in that interface because it can't hold values as you pointed, it's just a type of contract.

The value you get by submitting a form implements that interface, so it is consisted of the same properties. The value is just a part of that object that you passed as an argument and it has `.amount` property on it because it fulfills the `Income` interface.

Answer (score 1):

> it is just a contract and cannot hold values

Yes, but it can be a contract like "there is an `amount` property, of type `number`", i.e.

```
interface Income {
    amount: number
}
```

Any object *is-a* `Income` if it has an `amount`, and that `amount` *is-a* `number`

Comment: Oh ok. So I can pass any object as long as it has the required field? Sorry I came from Java and I'm confused with the idea

Comment: @DanielBristol In Java you can still pass any object that fulfills the interface. In fact, that's how you're supposed to work - Liskov's Substitution Principle (the **L** in SOLID) should be encouraging this behaviour. Your methods in Java should accept an interface like `List` or `Collection` instead of a concrete implementation like `ArrayList`. It's the same general idea with TS, only it uses structural equality. But point is still the same - there could be anything behind the interface. As long as it fulfills the contract.

Comment: @DanielBristol what Java lacks is combining `number getAmount(); void setAmount(number);` in one declaration, like C#'s `number amount { get; set }`.

Comment: @VLAZ I get it now thank you. You cleared out my confusion. Java has the same concept you're right.